# Is there any cordova (phonegap) plugin that allow you to hide /show an installed app on your device?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm looking for a plugin for Cordova/phonegap that allows you to hide/show an application installed on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show installed application list in your app? I quite don't understand but in case of searching for cordova plugins, I will recommend visiting https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: Yes, on my app I want to display all the installed apps on the users phone.

Answer (score 0):

I made an Android launcher in Cordova please add the following plugins

> https://github.com/Whebcraft/System_api
>
> https://github.com/Whebcraft/lanch1
>
> https://github.com/Whebcraft/installedapps

after that use this functions to generate the apps and icons, you can also launch the apps, see this js code https://gist.github.com/Whebcraft/3423a90ceaa4df21dc750722709382c2

Android only (for now).